# Can sympy perform a symbolic approximation?

Tags: python, sympy

If I have a function such as `f(x) = x/(x+1)`.

In sympy:

> lim f as x --> oo is 1,
>   lim f as x --> 0 is 0

I'm looking for a way to "symbolically approximate" such a function for the cases where x >> 1 and x << 1.  Is there a way for sympy to do this and give the result:

when x << 1, f goes to x
when x >> 1, f goes to 1

Comment: Just read your last sentence a little closer. I think `series` is indeed what you are looking for.

Comment: If an answer helped you solve your problem, you can mark it as "accepted".

Answer (score 1):

I'm unclear what exactly you are asking for. To take the symbolic limit, you can use the `limit` function

```
In [5]: limit(x/(x + 1), x, 0)
Out[5]: 0

In [6]: limit(x/(x + 1), x, oo)
Out[6]: 1
```

As far as "approximating" the function, perhaps you want the series expansion (around 0 and infinity, respectively)

```
In [7]: (x/(x + 1)).series(x, 0)
Out[7]:
     2    3    4    5    ⎛ 6⎞
x - x  + x  - x  + x  + O⎝x ⎠

In [8]: (x/(x + 1)).series(x, oo)
Out[8]:
  1    1    1    1    1        ⎛1        ⎞
- ── + ── - ── + ── - ─ + 1 + O⎜──; x → ∞⎟
   5    4    3    2   x        ⎜ 6       ⎟
  x    x    x    x             ⎝x        ⎠
```

The series expansions show the limits at 0 and infinity (the constant terms), and are accurate approximations for the function near 0 or infinity (respectively).

Comment: Yes, series is what I can use. if  fx = sympify('x/(1+x)'), then fx.series(x0=0, n=2).removeO() produces x, and fx.series(x0=oo, n=1).removeO() produces 1.  I didn't realize that low-order series expansion was essentially the approximationI was doing.  Thanks!